# my computer can't find my csv file in r

Tags: r, csv, rstudio, data-analysis

When I try to run my csv file in RStudio, it says

> ```
> "cannot open file 'bit121GBP.csv': No such file or directory
> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection"
> ```

```
mydata <- read.csv("bit121GBP.csv", header =TRUE)
```

Should I download it to a different place, because right now it's on my Desktop, or should I change the code?

Comment: You need to supply R not just with the file _name_, but with the _path_ to the file. This can either be _relative_ to the current working directory (check with `getwd()`) or _absolute_, i.e. a full path from the top level of the drive.

Comment: Alternatively,   use `mydata <- read.csv(file.choose(), "rt")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways you can read file.

For example, you have to downloaded in Desktop (example for mac) then

First: provide full path

```
mydata <- read.csv("/Users/test/Desktop/bit121GBP.csv", header =TRUE)
```

Second: Provide relative path

```
mydata <- read.csv("~/Desktop/bit121GBP.csv", header =TRUE)
```

Third: Set path

```
setwd("~/Desktop")
mydata <- read.csv("bit121GBP.csv", header =TRUE)
```

Comment: `provide full path` ... what you listed there would also be a relative path on Windows.

Comment: thank you so much, setting the path to my desktop worked!